# Calculate qubit state in terms of two states that are opposite points on Bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, bloch-sphere

I am new to quantum computing and reading the book "Introduction to Classical and Quantum Computing", by Wong ([link](http://www.thomaswong.net/)).

I do not understand how to calculate the qubit state for the below question. Can someone please help me understand the answer? Thanks

> **Excercis 2.11.**  The following two states are opposing points on the Bloch sphere:
> $$|a\rangle=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}|0\rangle+\frac{i}{2}|1\rangle,$$
> $$|b\rangle=\frac{i}{2}|0\rangle+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}|1\rangle.$$
> So, we can measure relative to them.  Now consider a qubit in the state
> $$\frac{1}{2}|0\rangle-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}|1\rangle.$$
>
> (a) Write the qubit's state in terms of $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$.
>
> (b) If you measure the qubit in the basis $\{|a\rangle,|b\rangle\}$, what states would you get and with what probabilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point here is that you're going to be able to write
$$
\frac12|0\rangle-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|1\rangle=\alpha|a\rangle+\beta|b\rangle.
$$
Your job is to find the parameters $\alpha,\beta$. You've got a few strategies open to you. In a simple case like this, you could just expand the states $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$. If you equate the coefficients for $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, you'll get two simultaneous equations that will let you find $\alpha,\beta$.

However, long-term, I wouldn't recommend that as a way of doing the calculation. Instead, try to think if there's a state $|c\rangle$ you could use to take the inner product with:
$$
\langle c|(\frac12|0\rangle-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|1\rangle)=\alpha\langle c|a\rangle+\beta \langle c|b\rangle.
$$
How does this help? If you can pick your $|c\rangle$ such that $\langle c|b\rangle=0$, then it immediately isolates the $\alpha$ term for you. Do you know any state with the required property?

Answer (score 2):

**a)** First rewrite the equations in terms of $\left| 0 \right>$ and $\left| 1 \right>$ as follows ([here is how to do so](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/30429/23560)):
$$\begin{aligned}
\left| 0 \right> &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| a \right> - \frac{i}{2}\left| b \right>\\
\left| 1 \right> &= -\frac{i}{2}\left| a \right> + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| b \right>\\
\end{aligned}$$

Then substitute as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2}\left| 0 \right> - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| 1 \right>&=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| a \right> - \frac{i}{2}\left| b \right>) - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(- \frac{i}{2}\left| a \right> + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| b \right>)\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left| a \right> - \frac{i}{4}\left| b \right> + \frac{\sqrt{3}i}{4}\left| a \right> - \frac{3}{4}\left| b \right>\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}(1 + i)}{4}\left| a \right> - \frac{i + 3}{4}\left| b \right>
\end{aligned}$$

**b)** The probability of $\left| a \right>$ and $\left| b \right>$ respectively is:
$$\begin{aligned}
\left| \frac{\sqrt{3}(1 + i)}{4} \right|^2 &= \left( \frac{\sqrt{3}(1 + i)}{4} \right) \left( \frac{\sqrt{3}(1 - i)}{4} \right) = \frac{3}{8}\\
\left| \frac{i + 3}{4} \right|^2 &= \left( \frac{i + 3}{4} \right) \left( \frac{3 - i}{4} \right) = \frac{5}{8}
\end{aligned}$$

---

It's worth noting that the author explains the process for these types of problems on page 88 and 89 [in the book](https://www.thomaswong.net/introduction-to-classical-and-quantum-computing-1e3p.pdf).

Comment: You need some kets on the RHS of your first two equations...

Comment: My mistake! Thanks for catching that @hft.