# Why is the conjugate being used when rewriting a qubit state in another basis?

Tags: quantum-state, bloch-sphere

I'm currently going through [Introduction to Classical and Quantum Computing](https://www.thomaswong.net/introduction-to-classical-and-quantum-computing-1e3p.pdf), by Thomas Wong, and I'm struggling with an example given on page 88 (point 4).

The author gives the two following states, which form a basis as they are on opposite points of the Block sphere:
$$\begin{align}
\left| a \right> &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| 0 \right> + \frac{i}{2}\left| 1 \right>\\
\left| b \right> &= \frac{i}{2}\left| 0 \right> + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| 1 \right>
\end{align}$$

He then writes $\left| 0 \right>$ and $\left| 1 \right>$ in terms of $\left| a \right>$ and $\left| b \right>$ as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\left| 0 \right> &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| a \right> - \frac{i}{2}\left| b \right>, \,\, \left| 1 \right> = -\frac{i}{2}\left| a \right> + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| b \right>
\end{align}$$

In the above equations, the author uses in both cases the conjugate of $\frac{i}{2}$. What's the reasoning behind that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $$\begin{align}
> \left| a \right> &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| 0 \right> + \frac{i}{2}\left| 1 \right> \tag{A}\\
> \left| b \right> &= \frac{i}{2}\left| 0 \right> + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| 1 \right> \tag{B}
> \end{align}$$

> He then writes $\left| 0 \right>$ and $\left| 1 \right>$ in terms of $\left| a \right>$ and $\left| b \right>$ as follows:
> $$\begin{align}
> \left| 0 \right> &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| a \right> - \frac{i}{2}\left| b \right>, \,\, \left| 1 \right> = -\frac{i}{2}\left| a \right> + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left| b \right>
> \end{align}$$

> In the above equations, the author uses in both cases the conjugate of $\frac{i}{2}$. What's the reasoning behind that?

There is no reasoning other than algebra. The rearrangement is literally just algebra. It may also help to recall that $\frac{1}{i} = -i$.

You rearrange the equations (the equations I tagged as "A" and "B" above) so that you have solved for $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. For example, multiply the equation I have tagged above as "A" by $2/i$ to find:
$$
|a\rangle \frac{2}{i} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{i}|0\rangle + |1\rangle
$$
and multiply the equation I have tagged above as "B" by $2/\sqrt{3}$ to find:
$$
|b\rangle\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}|0\rangle + |1\rangle
$$

Then subtracting the above two equations to solve for $|0\rangle$ gives:
$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}|b\rangle + 2i|a\rangle = \left(\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}+i\sqrt{3}\right)|0\rangle\;,
$$
and rearranging to isolate $|0\rangle$ on one side gives:
$$
|0\rangle = \frac{-i}{2}|b\rangle + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|a\rangle\;.
$$

You can similarly solve for $|1\rangle$ using algebra.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for this detailed explanation!